# Ideal theoretic proof of the first inequality of global class field theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In the old days(namely in the 1920s), global class field theory was stated and proved without using $\mathfrak p$-adic fields. I am interested in their methods, but unfortunately they were written in German and they are difficult to decipher at least for me.
In particular, I would like to prove the first inequality(see below) of global class field theory without using $\mathfrak p$-adic fields.

We use the terminology of Milne's online course note: Class Field Theory(2013).
Let $k$ be an algebraic number field(we always assume $[k : \mathbb Q] \lt \infty$).
Let $K/k$ be a finite cyclic extension of degree $n$.
Let $\mathfrak m$ be a modulus(Milne p.144) of $k$ such that $\mathfrak p | \mathfrak m$ if and only if $\mathfrak p$ is ramified(for the definition of ramification of a real infinite prime, see Milne p.4) in $K/k$.
We denote by $I_k(\mathfrak m)$ the group of nonzero fractional ideals of $k$ that are relatively prime to $\mathfrak m_0$, where $\mathfrak m_0$ is the finite part of $\mathfrak m$.
We denote by $I_K(\mathfrak m)$ the group of nonzero fractional ideals of $K$ that are relatively prime to $\mathfrak m_0 O_K$, where $O_K$ is the ring of integers in $K$.
We denote $i(k_{\mathfrak m, 1})$ (Milne p.145) by $R(\mathfrak m)$.
Hence $I_k(\mathfrak m)/R(\mathfrak m)$ is the ray class group modulo $\mathfrak m$ (Milne p.145).

The theorem of the first inequality of global class field theory states that there exists such $\mathfrak m$ such that $(I_k(\mathfrak m) : R(\mathfrak m)N_{K/k}(I_K(\mathfrak m))) \ge n$.

Reading a proof of this theorem in Takagi's Algebraic Number Theory(in Japanese),
I found that the aforementioned problem is reduced to proving the following theorem without using $\mathfrak p$-adic analysis.

**Theorem**
Let $K/k$ be as above.
Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of $k$ which is ramified in $K/k$.
We denote by $O_{k, \mathfrak p}$ the localization of $O_k$ at $\mathfrak p$.
Then there exists an integer $r_0 \ge 0$ such that
$(k^{\times}(\mathfrak p) : U_{\mathfrak p}^{(i)} N_{K/k}(K^{\times}(\mathfrak p O_K)) = e$ for all $i \ge r_0$,
where $k^{\times}(\mathfrak p)$ is the set of nonzero elements of $k$ that are relatively prime to $\mathfrak p$, $K^{\times}(\mathfrak p O_K)$ is the set of nonzero elements of $K$ that are relatively prime to $\mathfrak p O_K$, $U_{\mathfrak p}^{(i)} = \{\alpha \in O_{k, \mathfrak p}\ |\ \alpha \equiv 1 $ (mod $\mathfrak p^i O_{k, \mathfrak p})\}$, and $e$ is the ramification index of $\mathfrak p$.

**My question:** how do we prove this without using $\mathfrak p$-adic field?

**Remark**
For the reader's convenience, I will write a sketch of the usual proof of the theorem using $\mathfrak p$-adic analysis.
Let $Z$ be the decomposition group of $\mathfrak p$ with respect to $K/k$, $K^Z$ be the corresponding subfield of $K/k$.
By replacing $K$ by $K^Z$, we may assume that there exists only one prime ideal $\mathfrak P$ of $K$ lying over $\mathfrak p$. Namely $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak P^e$.
By taking $\mathfrak p$-adic completion, we may assume that $k$ is the $\mathfrak p$-adic field and that $K$ is the $\mathfrak P$-adic field.
Hence it sufices to prove that $(U_k : U_k^{(i)} N_{K/k}(U_K) = e$ for all $i \ge r_0$,
where $U_k$ and $U_K$ are the groups of units in $k$ and $K$ respectively and $U_k^{(i)} = \{\alpha \in O_k\ |\ \alpha \equiv 1 $ (mod $\mathfrak p^i )\}$.
It is well known that $U_k^{(i)} \subset (k^{\times})^n$ for sufficiently large $i$.
Hence $U_k^{(i)} \subset N_{K/k}(U_K)$ for sufficiently large $i$.
Hence it sufices to prove that $(U_k : N_{K/k}(U_K)) = e$.
But this is well known(see for example Lang's Algebraic Number Theory).

Comment: Take a look at the appendix in  Classical Invitation to Algebraic Numbers and Class Field Theory by Cohn. It accurately represents the early state of things.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Thanks. But it uses the $\mathfrak p$-adic method to prove the theorem.

Comment: ok so dont read it...

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Don't get me wrong. I thanked you for the info.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you interested in this?

Comment: @A.P. One reason is that ideals are more concrete and elementary than $\mathfrak p$-adic numbers.
For example, ideals are more suitable in concrete calculations.
Another reason is that knowing various proofs of a theorem is usually useful for better understanding of the theorem.
Finally I'm curious just like you.

Comment: Welcome back Makoto!  :)

Comment: I recall my professor said there has never been a way to give "purely global" proof of the results of global class field theory, you'll have to end up making local arguments somewhere.  Perhaps the original arguments in the 1920s didn't explicitly make reference to extensions of $p$-adic fields, but they were probably using local machinery, perhaps disguised.

Comment: @D_S "*but they were probably using local machinery, perhaps disguised.*"
Maybe so, but God is in the details.
How do you prove(or disguise) it without using the $\mathfrak p$-adic completion?
This is the very point of my question.